# Link from DB in FB plugin

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

I am trying to share my articles on FB by a button. The article and images are coming from Database. The Question is 
"**How do i Set the link and image on this hyperlink?**"
I want to set the `link`, `picture` and `Redirect_uri` properties from CodeBehind.

```
<td>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
  PostBackUrl="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=458358780877780&
  link=http://localhost:49441/ProjectLand/detail.aspx?id=14&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/" Text="Share"
  >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="FontSmall marginTop" style="font-size: 11pt;">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" CssClass="pnl1">
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="250px" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" CssClass="pnl2">
                <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" Width="680px" Height="300px" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Literal ID="ltlDesc" runat="server"></asp:Literal></div>
```

Images `img1`, `img2` and `ltlDesc` are populating from Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution 
See the link
[Custom Facebook Share Button in Asp.Net](http://dotnetgeekblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/custom-facebook-share-button-in-asp-net/)